# Is it possible to do a group chat in Linux Terminal over LAN?

Tags: terminal, lan, chat

I've used `netcat` to chat with my friend on the same LAN. However I want to know if it is possible to do a group chat in Linux Terminal over LAN?

Answer (score 3):

You could also look at `ytalk`, which was designed for this. It was pretty popular in the late '90s and the early '00s.

Answer (score 1):

`socat` can do this via multicast on a LAN.

```
host1:$ socat STDIO UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.1.0.1:6666,bind=:6666,range=192.168.1.0/24,ip-add-membership=224.1.0.1:192.168.1.11
host2:$ socat STDIO UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.1.0.1:6666,bind=:6666,range=192.168.1.0/24,ip-add-membership=224.1.0.1:192.168.1.12
host3:$ socat STDIO UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.1.0.1:6666,bind=:6666,range=192.168.1.0/24,ip-add-membership=224.1.0.1:192.168.1.13
```

The numbers here are:

- 224.1.0.1 - Multicast IP. Any multicast IP will work here. Needs to be the same on all clients.
- 6666 - Port number. Any unused number > 1024 will work. Same on all clients.
- 192.168.1.0/24 - Allowed client network range.
- 192.168.1.11 - Your host's IP address.

More info on using `socat` for multicast at http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html